# How can I fix wrong date format in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, strftime

I'm working on app where I use SQLite to store data.
I created column Date. Since I'm beginner I made a mistake by inputing date as %m/%d/%Y (for example: 2/20/2020)
Now I've got a problem while taking out rows between selected dates.
I tried using this code:
`SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Date BETWEEN strftime('%m/%d/%Y','2/5/2019') AND strftime('%m/%d/%Y','2/20/2020')`
But that's not working.

Example table:

```
ID | Date
01 | 9/2/2019
02 | 2/20/2020
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Use one of the date formats listed in [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) if you want to compare dates in any way but equality.

Comment: Save yourself all that trouble and update the date column to YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: How? When I use update table set Date = substr(Date, 6) || "-" || substr(Date,3,1) 
  || "-" || substr(date, 1,1); then 2/20/2020 becomes 2020-20-2/ but 9/2/2019 becomes 019-9/-2/ .. doesnt work properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your dates to the only valid for SQLite date format which is `YYYY-MM-DD`:

```
update tablename
set date = substr(date, -4) || '-' || 
           substr('00' || (date + 0), -2, 2) || '-' ||
           substr('00' || (substr(date, instr(date, '/') + 1) + 0), -2, 2);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wjzdCwmBLphGt4cymoBYzG/0).
Results:

```
| ID  | Date       |
| --- | ---------- |
| 1   | 2019-09-02 |
| 2   | 2020-02-20 |
```

Now you can set the conditions like:

```
Date BETWEEN '2019-02-05' AND '2020-02-20'
```

If you do this change then you can use the function `strftime()` in `select` statements to return the dates in any format that you want:

```
SELECT strftime('%m/%d/%Y', date) date FROM Table
```

If you don't change the format of date column then every time you need to compare dates you will have to transform the value with the expression used in the `UPDATE` statement, and this is the worst choice that you could make.